# Pumpkin or something else?

Tags: pumpkins, gourds

This was a volunteer growing I believe from whatever was in our compost from last year. There were pumkin seeds in the compost but I don't recall composting gourds. We live in MD ic it makes any difference for ID

Not sure how to add a photo here

Comment: Have a picture?

Comment: Welcome Lena! To add a picture, press the gray edit word under the question, or this [edit]. That will open the question. Along the top you'll see an icon that looks like a picture of a mountain. Press that and it will give you the option to add a picture from your computer or from a website. If that doesn't work easily for you, please let us know and we'll offer more help. This is an interesting question and we look forward to being able to answer it, and to getting to know you better!

Comment: Were there any other related seeds in that compost or are you just trying to tell if it's a pumpkin or a gourd?

Answer (score 6):

It's kind of difficult to gauge without a pic, but if you know for a fact they were pumpkin seeds, it's one of two things:

**1.** Your Original seed was an F1 hybrid and the progeny will almost never come true from seed.

**or**

**2.** If your seed was from homogeneous seed stock, what you have is the result of cross pollination, where the pollen from another gourd (via wind, bees, Butterflies, hummingbirds, etc.) pollinated your pumpkin's flower resulting in an F1 hybrid (Your new gourd).

The above only applies if the subject of this question is a mature, yet unidentifiable fruit of the gourd family.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What a wonderful explanation, iuppiter!!  Please continue to help us on this site!

Comment: Don't forget the possibility of mutations (although I would think something else happened).

Comment: @stormy Thank you. I'll be more than happy to help when I can.